# MSYS2: Setting up an Opengl development environment

Tags: opengl, msys2

I have successfully installed Msys2 and mingw (mingws for 32 bit and 64 bit building). Now, I want to setup Opengl libraries for development. Which packages should I install using pacman? And for compiling an application using opengl and other popular opengl libraries which linker library flags do I need?
(My main needs are GLU, GLUT and GLEW but if you inform about the other libraries available in MSYS2 that would be great!)

Comment: First, I'm MSYS2 developer.
Second, why not ask directly on MSYS2 ML or IRC?
Third, what OpenGL libraries do you need?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Depends on what you need you can install 32-bit - mingw-w64-i686-{free glut,glew,SDL,SDL2} or 64-bit - mingw-w64-x86_64-{free glut,glew,SDL,SDL2} packages.

Comment: Thank you. If you would like to extend this for whatever possible in name of opengl such as `glm` etc. please post an answer. That would be great. :)

Comment: You always can see what packages we have here: https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages.

Comment: Or search package via package manager: pacman -Ss "value"

Answer (score 5):

That typically is done by (e.g)

```
pacman -Ss glew
```

and then picking the package that you want from that result and doing (again e.g.)

```
pacman -S  mingw-w64-i686-glew
```

Note that you need to use the correct bitness (i686 = 32 bit in this example).